# Swagger with abstract Class hierarchy, should work

Tags: java, spring, openapi, code-first, openapi-generator

Ok, lets step in of what we have and the issues we are currently facing....

We have a data model, pretty close to that what is available in other examples.
(all code here in github: https://github.com/straube-jens/swagger)

We have a Basis DTO Class *RsvXO* (shitty Name, I know…) which has a List of Class *Pet* inside. *Pet* is an abstract Class and is implemented by *Cat* and *Dog* Class. Service Endpoint is delivering the basis class *RsvXO*. We put the Json Annotations for referencing the Classes *Cat* and *Dog* out of *Pet*.

We add the spring swagger-ui dependency to the pom and ran all that, to get the openapi description out of “swagger” generated.

Sure, there is documentation that writes that polymorphic is not covered by openapi which is actually not true for this example, but we will see later.

The generated description looks like the following example:

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "info": {
        "title": "OpenAPI definition",
        "version": "v0"
    },
    "servers": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
            "description": "Generated server url"
        }
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/vehicleDecision": {
            "post": {
                "tags": [
                    "rest-service"
                ],
                "operationId": "createRiskDecission",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "rsvXO",
                        "in": "query",
                        "required": true,
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RsvXO"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "OK",
                        "content": {
                            "*/*": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RsvXO"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "Cat": {
                "type": "object",
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "preferredGardenToPeeIn": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Dog": {
                "type": "object",
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "preferredPostman": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Pet": {
                "required": [
                    "petType"
                ],
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "petType": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "discriminator": {
                    "propertyName": "petType"
                }
            },
            "RsvXO": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "pet": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "oneOf": [
                                {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Cat"
                                },
                                {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Dog"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "aenderDatum": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "date-time"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If we use the description on the client side to generate the data model, we get some wired implementation then. The generator is creating the *Pet*, the *Dog* and the *Cat* Classes as needed, that’s fine.

But is generates the for the Pet-relation in *RsvXO* another Class called *RsvXOPetInner* Class which is an exact copy of *Pet*. It sets the attribute inside the *RsvXO* to the type of *RsvXOPetInner* Class.
But there is no relation to *Pet* Class in *RsvXO* or *RsvXOPetInner*.

So, it is technically not possible to set a *Dog* or a *Cat* instance inside the List in *RsvXO*, because the type of the Classes does not fit.

**BUT**

We changed the description json which was generated by the Server by hand. Available in the next post:

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "info": {
        "title": "OpenAPI definition",
        "version": "v0"
    },
    "servers": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
            "description": "Generated server url"
        }
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/vehicleDecision": {
            "post": {
                "tags": [
                    "rest-service"
                ],
                "operationId": "createRiskDecission",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "rsvXO",
                        "in": "query",
                        "required": true,
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RsvXO"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "OK",
                        "content": {
                            "*/*": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RsvXO"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "Cat": {
                "required": [
                    "petType"
                ],
                "type": "object",
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
                    }
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "preferredGardenToPeeIn": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "Dog": {
                "required": [
                    "petType"
                ],
                "type": "object",
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
                    }
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "preferredPostman": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "Pet": {
                "oneOf": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Cat"
                    },
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Dog"
                    }
                ],
                "required": [
                    "petType"
                ],
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "petType": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "discriminator": {
                    "propertyName": "petType"
                }
            },
            "RsvXO": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "pet": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
                        }
                    },
                    "aenderDatum": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "date-time"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the client generator works over that json, the generated model looks perfect.
So, there should actually be an option to build polymorphic data model structures with openapi, right?

Sure there is a ArraySchema and Schema Annotation from swagger, that we used as well, but the documentation (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations)
for that annotations does not cover our case.

We did the last 3 days a lot of try and error and decide now to ask the community for help.

So please check out the test-project from github (https://github.com/straube-jens/swagger) and hopefully you will have a solution or another hint for us.

Greetings and thanks a lot, Katrin and Jens